# Difference between Metadata-DBConnection And tDBConnection. Is there any correlation?

Tags: etl, talend

Why do I see disconnected when I run this tDB Connection?

Below log when I run `tdbConnection`.

Is it automatically getting disconnected?

```
[statistics] connecting to socket on port number 3024
[statistics] connected
[statistics] disconnected
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference between metadata dbConnection and tdbConection. Metadata is the one you get from any database schema and utilize it, where as tdbConnection is the one in which you manually provided the details of the database details like schema, port, user, password, database and host.

The above issue would be because your database is inconsistent and the talend is unable to connect to it. May be there would be a latency issue. You can enable tdie and tlogcatcher and get the detailed logs